# Is GAE Channel API secure? And what is the underlying implementation?

Tags: python, security, google-app-engine, https, channel-api

I'm using GAE + Python to create an application that needs to send real-time updates of sensitive data to clients and I wanted to know if the [App Engine Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview) is secure or not. Will using HTTPS be enough or do channels require their own security protocol?

Also, what is the underlying implementation of the [App Engine Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview)?  Websockets, SSE?  It seems like it really only provides one way communication from server to client through the channel, and then has the client use a standard HTTP request to communicate with the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connections to the channel API are made over HTTPS, regardless of how your page was loaded, so it's not possible to eavesdrop on the contents of a channel API connection. As long as you keep the channel key secret, then, your channel is a secure communications channel between your app and the client.

Channels are implemented using long polling (comet).

Comment: That's good to know.  How did you come across this information?  I didn't see this in the GAE dev pages.  Also, it kind of sounds to me like Google just created the channel api as an excuse to charge people for another service.  What's to stop me from just implementing webosckets or SSE myself for free?  Or to even use long polling for that matter (aside from the fact that GAE limits request to 30-60 seconds or something like that)?

Comment: You could implement long-polling yourself (I've seen code that does this, but the person who implemented it switched to the Channel API when it was available). You'll almost certainly pay much more in instance-hours than you would if you used the Channel API.

Comment: @Nick Johnson Never mind, I see you're a developer for GAE and that's why you know.

Comment: To clarify: Channels fall back on long polling, but they will use more advanced/modern implementations for browser push if those are available.

Answer (score 0):

Because channels are long-term-alive connections between server and a client, channels are not allowed to use resource consuming security approaches in many cases due to performance consideration. As it is declared in the [official manual](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview), The server only receives update messages from clients via HTTP requests. And as far as I know, even Dropbox sends its long-term notify message via HTTP, using a very short notify only to tell whether there is something new.

Fortunately, there are two ways to ensure your security.

1. Only notify your client via the HTTP channel when some states change. After that, let the client decide whether a further request, which can be a secure communication, should be made. And this is the most common way channels are used.
2. Although this is not the way I personally recommended, you can encrypt your data yourself and put these encrypted data run on the insecure HTTP channel.

Comment: So you're saying that channels are not secure as is because they use HTTP and not HTTPS?